# How to distinguish between an answered and unanswered call in Twilio?

Tags: node.js, twilio

I'm working on a Node.js web app that uses Twilio to place a call to a user. It's all working nicely, but I'm struggling to figure out how to distinguish an answered call from an unanswered one. The code that makes the call looks like this:

```js
client.makeCall({
  to: to,
  from: config.sendingNumber,
  url: config.baseUrl + '/call-answered?' + queryString,
  method: 'GET',
  statusCallback: config.baseUrl + '/call-status?' + queryString,
  statusCallbackMethod: 'GET',
  statusCallbackEvent: 'answered',
});
```

(For what it's worth, `queryString` just lets me pass over an identifier for the user so I can do appropriate stuff).

The way things currently seem to work is that `url` gets called only when the user answers the call (and it provides the markup for the call), while `statusCallback` seems to get called whether the call is answered or it's dismissed without answering (and either way, `req.query.CallStatus` is set as `in-progress`). So I can currently positively detect an answered call, but have no way of knowing for sure when a call is not answered (other than just waiting and seeing, which is non-ideal).

Ideally I'd like to either **a)** have a callback that is only fired if the call is not answered, or **b)** receive some call status info that lets me distinguished between an answered call and one that wasn't answered. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I managed to get this working via the `completed` event, as suggested by Megan Speir (thanks!), but by a slightly different route.

For some reason, I seem to get an `in-progress` status for calls whether I answer them or hang up (I never get, eg. `canceled`). However, because the main URL is only called on a successful answered call, I was able to distinguish between an answered and unanswered call by setting a call-status variable to `call-answered` when a call was answered, and then checking for this value in the callback for the `completed` event - ie. if it's set to `call-answered` then this is the end of a successfully answered call; otherwise it's the end of an unanswered call. This seems to work for both dismissed calls and ones that go to an answering machine (at least with the phone I'm testing with at the moment).

Answer (score 2):

You can specify multiple events by providing multiple [`StatusCallbackEvent` values](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-event-parameter).

```
// Download the Node helper library from twilio.com/docs/node/install
// These vars are your accountSid and authToken from twilio.com/user/account
var accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
var authToken = "AUTH_TOKEN";
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls.create({
    url: "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
    to: "+14155551212",
    from: "+18668675309",
    statusCallback: "https://www.myapp.com/events",
    statusCallbackMethod: "POST",
    statusCallbackEvent: ["answered", "completed"],
    method: "GET"
}, function(err, call) {
    process.stdout.write(call.sid);
});
```

Now, the `completed` event will be fired regardless given the following `CallStatus` values: (`busy`, `canceled`, `completed`, `failed`, or `no-answer`).

The real trick however, is that if the call reaches an answering machine it will be considered `answered`. I've written this [blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/tracking-call-status-how-can-you-tell-if-a-human-answers-the-phone-2.html) to talk about one way you can work around this using the [`<Gather>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) to detect if a human answers the phone.

Comment: Thanks for the response! That definitely looks promising, but doesn't quite seem to get round the issue that even when I dismiss the call, the call status is still "in-progress". I've tried it with both events, as you suggest, but whether I answer or dismiss the call I still get the same pair of statuses ("in-progress", followed by "complete"). So, unless I'm missing something, I still can't distinguish between answered and unanswered calls...

Comment: (Though having said that, the "completed" status might well be enough for me to do what I need to do... Will test that. Probably on Monday though! Thanks again)

Comment: Let me know how it goes Nick!

Comment: Hi Megan, just to let you know, I couldn't quite get it working this way (for some reason I still got an `in-progress` call status even for unanswered calls), but in the end I was able to get it working using the `completed` event alone so thanks for suggesting that. If it's of interest, I've posted the details of what worked for me as a separate answer. Thanks again for the help!